# How to deal with "Cannot export init__init__: symbol not defined"

Tags: python, gcc, mingw32

I was to install the python package "wheezy.template" on my 64bit windows.
Here is what it shows after $pip install wheezy.template$.  How to solve it?

```
building 'wheezy.template.utils' extension

C:\anaconda\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c src\wheezy\template\utils.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\utils.o

src\wheezy\template\utils.c: In function '__Pyx_RaiseArgtupleInvalid':

src\wheezy\template\utils.c:2100:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]

src\wheezy\template\utils.c:2100:18: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 5 has type 'Py_ssize_t' [-Wformat]

src\wheezy\template\utils.c:2100:18: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat]

src\wheezy\template\utils.c:2100:18: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\utils.def

C:\anaconda\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\utils.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\utils.def -LC:\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\wheezy\template\utils.pyd

building 'wheezy.template.__init__' extension

C:\anaconda\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -mdll -O -Wall -IC:\Anaconda\include -IC:\Anaconda\PC -c src\wheezy\template\__init__.c -o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\__init__.o

writing build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\__init__.def

C:\anaconda\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DMS_WIN64 -shared -s build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\__init__.o build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\wheezy\template\__init__.def -LC:\Anaconda\libs -LC:\Anaconda\PCbuild\amd64 -lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win-amd64-2.7\wheezy\template\__init__.pyd


Cannot export init_init_: symbol not defined

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: That *is* an interesting error, given that according to the documentation - *and the source code* - wheezy.template is written in Python, not in C. But I can confirm that on my Linux system, `pip install wheezy.template` finds a parser.c to compile (although it successfully compiles, so I can't duplicate your exact error). I used pip's --download-cache option to take a look at the source archive pip actually downloaded - it has no C files in it. There seems to be no reason at all that installing this should run gcc - but it does.